# Finding duplicate records by searching a few characters

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, duplicates

I know there are many questions answered under this title. But I believe I have a unique situation where I need a specific way to find and export the duplicate data from my database.

I have a database with over 20.000 contacts. I need a query to find duplicate records in the contacts table. But since there are many same last names, or first names for different people, I want to lookup the first few characters of the first name and the last name to see if there is a duplicate record matching the query.

So, the query could be explained like this: Look at the first two characters from the firstName column, then look at the first three characters from the lastName column, and show it with any similar records.

I would highly appreciate any advice. Thank you.

Comment: Please read the following article on how to ask a question on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I appreciate it. But I don't understand what is wrong with my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it, assuming your contacts table is called contacts:

```
select * 
from contacts c 
join contacts c2 on c2.id!=c.id
and left(c2.firstName,2)=left(c.firstName,2)
and left(c2.lastName,3)=left(c.lastName,3)
```

Comment: Can you tell me what do "c" and "c2" refer to in this case?

Comment: They are aliases referring to the tables. Using `... from contacts c` then `c.firstName` is effectively writing `contacts.firstName`

Comment: Oh sure. But I am trying to find the duplicates only within the contacts table. So there is no second table to compare. Is it still possible?

Comment: The contacts table is the first and second table. It's joining on itself where the names match and the id doesn't (otherwise every row would be returned)

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Thank you for the explanation. 

So, I tested the query, and I am not sure it does what I need. I basically created two duplicate records to test it out, and then ran it. The result doesn't show the record(s) I created for test purposes. Any idea why?

Comment: can you please put the test rows in a comment?

Comment: Sertug Yesil     24144;
Sertug Yesil     24145

Comment: Sorry, can't format it in a readable way. 24144 and 24145 are the ids.

Comment: It should be returning 2 rows ie `Sertug Yesil 24144; Sertug Yesil 24145` and `Sertug Yesil 24145; Sertug Yesil 24144`. Remove the `c2.id!=c.id` and the first `and` and see what happens

Comment: I don't know what that query returned, but definitely not the one I was looking for. This is what the query looks like after following the suggestion: `select * 
from contactsCopy c 
join contactsCopy c2 on left(c2.FirstName,2)=left(c.FirstName,2)
and left(c2.LastName,3)=left(c.LastName,3)`

Comment: It should have returned every match, including every record matching itself. If you dont know how to use a join then you should google it and learn it

Comment: Are you saying the query I referenced above is wrong? Isn't that what you suggested me to do? What is it have to do with not knowing how to use a join?

Comment: The query above is what you should have used. A join is a crucial part of a query and if you aren't doing it right you'll run into issues without noticing. The script above should work. Copy + Paste the script from my answer and only change the table name then let me know the results eg an error or no results

Comment: But that is the query I used it in the first place. And it didn't return the duplicates. Then I changed it to what you suggested, that didn't return duplicates neither. I am not an idiot :) Of course I am changing the table names. Would you please kindly write the query in your next answer, so I know what you mean?

Comment: What returned when you ran it? It may help debug whats going on?

Comment: It is really hard to say what it returned as it had bunch of records that weren't duplicates. I believe it returned the records that have the same first 2 letters from the FirstName, and first 3 letters from the LastName. But shouldn't have that also returned the exact duplicate record I created for testing? But it didn't.

Comment: OK so it is working. Try: `select *  
from contacts c  
join contacts c2 on c2.id!=c.id  
and left(c2.firstName,2)=left(c.firstName,2)  
and left(c2.lastName,3)=left(c.lastName,3)  
order by c.id desc`

Comment: This is the error I am getting now for the first time:  _#2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query_

Comment: Ok well did you run it again? did it take any longer than usual?

Comment: Yes it is taking longer than usual. I assume it is timing out while running it.

Comment: thats really weird. what indexes have you currently got? also, maybe try adding `WHERE c.firstName = 'Sertug'` which should speed it up and tell you whether it's meeting the condition

Comment: ok well if you found my answer useful please set as top answer and upvote. let me know if i need to update the query

Comment: I believe it is a sufficient query.